# A comedy movie about a detective and three women

Tags: identify-this-movie

I remember watching a Hollywood comedy movie in 2001 on Star Movies channel in India.  The movie was from the 1990's.  I have forgotten the name of the movie, but here is the plot:

There is a detective and three ladies.
The first lady is the detective's wife, who is cheating on him and is planning with her boyfriend to kill him. The second lady is the Detective's assistant who is kind of cute and has a crush on the detective. The third lady is rich, wild, and highly sexual. She becomes obsessed with the detective.

The story revolves around these characters.

Please help me to identify this movie.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty certain you mean the parody thriller [Fatal Instinct](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0106873/combined) with Armand Assante as the Private Investigator, Sherilyn Fenn from Twin Peaks as the secretary in love with him. The wife is played by Kate Nelligan, and the client by Sean Young, looking every bit as hot as she was in Dune and Blade Runner. This is a parody of detective thrillers by Hitchcock and Brian DePalma.
Here's the synopsis from [imdb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0106873/plotsummary):
*A spoof of the late 80s and early 90s suspense thrillers and murder mysteries, including Basic Instinct, Sleeping With The Enemy, Cape Fear and others. A cop/attorney (yes he's both) is seduced by a woman while his wife is having an affair with a mechanic. Lots of other sublots and visual gags in the style of Naked Gun.*